# Different behaviour of "export = class"

Tags: typescript, export, typescript1.6

I am writing an external module (using AMD) that needs to export only a single class. I want to simply import it as `import MyClass = require('./MyClass')`, therefore in MyClass module I use "export =" syntax:

```
export = class MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

This compiles without errors and produces reasonable JS code:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    return (function () {
        function MyClass() { /* ... */ }
        return MyClass;
    })();
});
```

Next, I try to import it:

```
import MyClass = require('./MyClass');
var my: MyClass = new MyClass();
```

Compiling this gives me error at "var my: MyClass": "TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyClass'".

But, when I change my module export to:

```
class MyClass {
    // ...
}
export = MyClass;
```

everything works okay, however produced JS code seems to be almost the same:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function MyClass() { /* ... */ }
        return MyClass;
    })();
    return MyClass;
});
```

As far as I can see, the only difference is, it uses temporary variable before return, which has no effect outside of this closure.

So what's the difference and why I get TS2304 error in first case? Should not both cases work the same?

Answer (score 0):

> Should not both cases work the same?

They should. Please report an error here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: I did report it, but I turned out there's no error. Those cases are not the same. I re-posted the explanation given by one of typescript's devs as an answer here. Thanks for pointing me at their issues page though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I've been given at [TypeScript's issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5377) on GitHub. 
Credit goes to [Vladimir Matveev](https://github.com/vladima).

> this is by design. Declaration of class `MyClass` has meanings of both
>   type and value. As for class expression if it has name then this name
>   is added to type\value declaration spaces **inside** the class expression.
>   Outside you can bind class expression to either variable or parameter
>   but this binding will only have value meaning. As a consequence:
>
> ```
> var x = class A {
>     f() {
>         let a: A; // legal - A has type meaning
>         a = new A(); // legal = A has value meaning
>     }
> }
> let y1: A; // illegal - A is not visible here
> let y2: x; // illegal - variable declaration adds name `x` only to value declaration space
> let y3 = new x(); // legal - x has value meaning
> ```